# MySQL IF/ELSE statements in WHERE

Tags: mysql

I want to look for duplicate members in the database.

1. First I want to check if their username exists.
2. If not, I want to check their first name, last name and email address.
3. Lastly if that doesn't match anyone, I want to just check if a first name and last name exists.

I've been looking at IF/ELSE statements and even CASE in Google but I can't seem to figure out how it would work in my situation.

Here's some code that in my mind makes sense (being a PHP programmer) but it isn't how MySQL does things...

```
SELECT id FROM members WHERE (
    IF (member_username = 'john.doe')
    ELSEIF (member_firstname = 'John' AND member_lastname = 'Doe' AND member_email = 'john@doe.com')
    ELSE (member_firstname = 'John' AND member_lastname = 'Doe')
) AND deleted = 0
```

How would I translate the above into working MySQL code if it's even possible.

Comment: I would use: `SELECT username, first_name, last_name, email_addr FROM members WHERE username = 'username' OR (first_name = 'first name' AND last_name = 'last name')` then determine which of the 3 situations happened in whatever programming language you're using (or are you trying to do it solely in MySQL?)

Comment: @Corbin I was hoping to do it in MySQL soley but what you've suggested would work well too. I think I might go with your option as it seems to be the safest compared to the other answers I've received so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking @Corbin's advice and used

```
SELECT username, first_name, last_name, email_addr FROM members WHERE username = 'username' OR (first_name = 'first name' AND last_name = 'last name')
```

And then used PHP if/else statements to determine which record was the exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

What would be wrong with this?

```
SELECT id
FROM members
WHERE (member_username = 'john.doe'
    OR (member_firstname = 'John' AND member_lastname = 'Doe' AND member_email = 'john@doe.com')
    OR (member_firstname = 'John' AND member_lastname = 'Do'))
AND deleted = 0
```

Comment: I wanted it to check whether the name and email address exists before I check if just the name exists.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget **TOP 1!**

```
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM members WHERE deleted = 0 AND
(
  (member_username = 'john.doe') OR
  (member_email = 'john@doe.com' AND member_firstname = 'John' AND member_lastname = 'Doe') OR
  (member_firstname = 'John' AND member_lastname = 'Doe')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case